# Creating phonegap project offline

Tags: cordova

i'm trying to create phonegap project

```
phonegap create AppName
```

with this result

```
Creating a new cordova project.
Downloading hello-world-template library for www...
Undefined
```

since "downloading" word is there.. i assume the command need to executed online..
so try again with this result

```
Creating a new cordova project.
Downloading hello-world-template library for www...
Download complete
```

so the question.. is there any way to execute the command offline..?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the `create` step by getting the same hello world app from here https://github.com/apache/cordova-app-hello-world

And then enter the project directory and execute the build command (e.g. `phonegap local build android`) and when the build is successful you can run the app (e.g. with `phonegap run android`).

Comment: acctually i know that trick, but it looks like phonegap is getting everything online.. i execute `phonegap local build android` and got this message `[warning] The command 'phonegap local <command>' has been DEPRECATED.
[warning] The command has been delegated to 'phonegap <command>'.
[warning] The command 'phonegap local <command>' will soon be removed.` bla..bla.. `Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.0.0/gradle-1.0.0.jar'.` bla..bla..`BUILD FAILED`

Comment: I think you'll have to execute the first time with the computer being online, in order to download the dependencies like gradle.. after that It should work offline.

Comment: You can also try using `cordova` which is the open source base of `phonegap`, but you'll get the same results.

Comment: you are right martin, the 'create' command need online only the first time.. thank's.